# mdl dialog executed multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

as quite standard thing i've a button launching an mdl modal dialog having the two usual buttons, confirm and cancel, but i got a "weird" behaviour:

the first time dialog is opened everything goes fine but if i reopen it (without refreshing the page) the code it's executed twice, opening it once again (without refreshing the page) the code it's executed three times, and so on ...
it seems that, without refreshing the page, the istances of dialog accumulates.

the html code for dialog, as suggested by mdl directives,is directly under the **body** tag

```
<body>

  ...

  <!-- START OF DUMMY DIALOG -->
  <dialog id="dummy-dialog" class="mdl-dialog">
    <!-- Title -->
    <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Dummy dialog</h4>
    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
      <p>Hi, I'm a dummy dialog and my purpose is to check why istances accumulates.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Actions -->
    <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
      <button id="dummy-send" type="button" class="mdl-button" >CONFIRM</button>
      <button id="dummy-close" type="button" class="mdl-button">CANCEL</button>
    </div>
  </dialog>
  <!-- END OF DUMMY DIALOG -->

  ...

</body>
```

the js code is like the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...
  $('#button').on('click', function(event) {
    showDummyDialog();
  });
  ...
});

...

function showDummyDialog() {
  const $dummyDialog = $('#dummy-dialog');
  $dummyDialog[0].showModal();

  $dummyDialog.on('click', function(event) {
    switch (event.target.id) {
      case 'dummy-send':
        console.log('confirm pressed');
        $dummyDialog[0].close();
        break;
      case 'dummy-close':
        console.log('cancel pressed');
        $dummyDialog[0].close();
        break;
    }
  });

  $dummyDialog.on('close', function (event) {
    console.log('dummy is closing');
  });
}
```

i'm testing it in chrome and in production the dialog will be polyfilled.

anybody so kind to addresss me to understand this behaviour? thanks

btw, here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r08y/9obkhwp3/27/) which "unfortunately" works properly :-(

Comment: You talk about test and prod environment. Does it not working in both ?

Comment: not yet, actually i'm emulating firebase hosting, which will host final version.

Comment: The problem is that yoiur snippet code works like a charm...

Comment: you mean the fiddle? if so yes is very frustrating i cannot get why in my testing there's this strange behaviour

Comment: Do you any other libraries used in your code ? Any more complete code ?

Comment: tested in firebase hosting too, same problem. libraries? i use jquery, firebase, dialog-polyfill and mdl design libraries (the dialogs contain mdl objects like checkboxes and textfields)